# Dynamic Dropdown has 0 Height

Tags: javascript, dynamic, dropdown, materialize

I'm trying to dynamically create HTML cards in javascript that include a [Materialize dropdown-trigger](https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html).

```
    posts.forEach(function(element) {
        ....  
        message += '<a class="dropdown-trigger btn-flat" data-target="drop1">';
        message += '<i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>';
        message += '</a>';
        document.getElementById("post" + index).innerHTML = message;
        index++;
      }, this);
      M.AutoInit();
```

HTML menu content:

```
     <ul id="drop1" class="dropdown-content">
         <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
         <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
         <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
     </ul>
```

If I create the buttons not using the dynamic addition, everything works as expected.  By dynamically adding them as shown above, the content of the menu has a height of 0:

[image]

...even though inspection shows it should have a height of 50px:

[image]

I've also tried:

Adding unique dropdown-content for each post (trigger1 opens drop1, trigger2 opens drop2, etc.)

Initializing each Trigger individually.

Comment: Well it is natural that it doesn't work. When you initialize your components they look for classes or identifiers that defines their behavior (like dropdown trigger) and attach those behaviors. And you are creating elements after those comppnenets initialized so they don't have attached behaviors. What you need to do is re initialize all components or initialize comoponent you create manually

Comment: @Eldar Thanks for the reply.  I'm not sure if you're familiar with the Materialize library, but the M.AutoInit() command should re-initialize the new components.

Comment: "Auto Init allows you to initialize all of the Materialize Components with a single function call. It is important to note that you cannot pass in options using this method." That shouldn't mean it should initialize components added dynamically after the function call

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce the issue you are having but below solution may give an idea or may be helpful to solve the issue. Also, note that some assumptions are made in below code part.

```js
var index = 1;
var posts = ["post1", "post2", "post3", "post4", "post5"];

posts.forEach(function(element) {
  let post = document.createElement('div');
  post.id = "post" + index;
  document.body.appendChild(post);

  // Remaining work..

  let cloneDrop = document.getElementById("dropTemplate").cloneNode(true);
  cloneDrop.style.visibility = "visible";
  cloneDrop.id = "drop" + index;
  document.getElementById("post" + index).appendChild(cloneDrop);

  // Remaining work..

  let message = '<a class="dropdown-trigger btn-flat" data-target="drop' + index + '">';
  message += '<i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>';
  message += '</a>';
  document.getElementById("post" + index).innerHTML += message;

  index++;
}, this);

M.AutoInit();
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    </head>
    <body>
       <ul id="dropTemplate" style="visibility: hidden" href="#" class="dropdown-content">
           <li><a href="#!">one</a></li> 
           <!-- 
           Also, if <li/> element is being overridden by a stylesheet, following approach can be tried. (Of course, it is not so correct way) 
           <li style="width: 100px important; height: 50px !important">...</li> 
           -->
           <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
           <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
       </ul>
    
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

JSFiddle Live Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ErdSavasci/vs37au84/